# Filter data.table columns by vector of characters inside an environment

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a nice way to effectuate the following (subsetting a data.table to certain columns based on a variable from an environment - or even a vector inside a list)?

```
envir <- new.env()
envir$list_of_fields <- c("Column1", "Column2")
```

```
dt[, ..envir$list_of_fields] # Doesn't work
```

I COULD do this, but there's got to be a better way.

```
list_of_fields <- envir$list_of_fields
dt[, ..list_of_fields] # This works, but instantiating a variable just for this is ugly
rm(list_of_fields)
```

Comment: `dt[, mget(envir$list_of_fields)]`

Comment: `dt[, envir$list_of_fields, with=FALSE]` also works.

Comment: @Roland Great idea. I was thinking I had to use some data.table feature, when a base R one would do! Could you please create an answer so I can accept it

Comment: @YHJang That would work well, but I got the impression this is a feature we're not supposed to use in new code, as it's old data.table behaviour

Comment: `dt[, .SD, .SDcols = envir$list_of_fields]` also works fine